# .NET WebService Security who can see and use

Tags: .net, security, web-services

Trying to firgure out how to test the security of a WebService.

Is there some way to search a site for webservices?

I have 2 applications one has a webservice and the other a reference to that service. I let visual studio build the reference in the App_WebReferences folder.

The webservice works, but i started wondering, can anyone access this service from any website? If so, how can i test this? How do you search a site for webservices?
Could I use jQuery/JSON code from a simple site to access a webservice?

I guess if it is not secure, how do you secure a webservice?

Answer (score 0):

This might give you some ideas: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/ws/2003/03/04/security.html

HTH.